# How do I control window placement in KDE with keyboard?

Tags: kde, window, shortcut-keys

Is it possible in KDE to set up keyboard shortcuts similar to what Unity uses for window placement - i.e. Alt - Ctrl - Numpad 6 to make a window occupy the left half of the screen etc.?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The KDE global keyboard shortcuts: System Settings > Shortcuts and Gestures > Global Keyboard Shortcuts. Pick the KWIN as the KDE component. You could set the keyboard shortcuts to the window position/tiling etc...

Answer (score 53):

More precisely:

1. `System Settings -> Shortcuts and Gestures -> Global Keyboard Shortcuts`
2. KDE component: `KWin ▼`
3. `Quick Tile Window to the Left` etc.

There is also somewhat interesting `Enable/Disable Tiling`, which defaults to `Alt+Shift+F11`. Unfortunately I could not figure out how to move tile a window so that it consumes top or bottom of the screen, but other hotkeys can be used to achieve that.

Comment: It's worth noting that native tiling support in KWin was removed in KDE 4.10. The functionality can now be attained via a KWin script: https://www.kde-look.org/content/show.php/Tiling?content=161151

Comment: For possible future reference, these tiling shortcuts are in version 5.8.7. I'm not positive, but I think it's built-in and not from a script.

Answer (score 23):

I was looking for a way to mimic the Microsoft Windows 7 window placement via keyboard including the windows (start) key.

Similar to the other answers I went:

1. Component:
   `System Settings`
   `-> Shortcuts`
   `--> Global Shortcuts`
   `---> System Settings Module` (KDE Plasma Version: 5.9.5)
   `---> KWin` (KDE Plasma Version: 5.9.12)
2. Action: 
   `Quick Tile Window to the {Left|Right}` etc.
3. Used key-combinations: `Meta+Left`, `Meta+Right`

here: the meta key is the name for the MS Windows start key.

(KDE Plasma Version: 5.9.5)
[image]

(KDE Plasma Version: 5.9.12)
[image]

Comment: For the German users: the translation is not literal. Look for `Fenster am {linken|rechten} Bildschirmrand anordnen`

Comment: On Kubuntu 18.04 with KDE Plasma 5.12, the Quick Tile shortcuts are under "KWin" instead of "System Settings Module".